# GWT: Creating a new object when I click on a button

Tags: gwt, polymer

When I try to create a new object at clicking a button, the created object does not look okay.

This is what I do:

```
@UiHandler("button")

protected void onButtonClick(ClickEvent e) {
    RootPanel.get().clear();
    RootPanel.get().add(new UserLandingPage());
}
```

Comment: `RootPanel.get().clear()` seems like a bad idea. What are you trying to do _exactly_? Also "_created object does not look okay_" isn't exactly what I'd call a technical description of the problem you are having...

Comment: I want to replace the whole page with a new panel. The thing is if I initialize UserLandingPage in the constructor every thing is fine.

Comment: However, when I create the object in the method, it does not work.

Comment: The other thing is that the page looks fine in Safari but not in Chrome !! which I dont understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The GWT way of switching from a set of widgets to a totally different one is through Activities and Places.

All you need is to follow the google examples on how use the MVP framework.

I collected some demos at the repo below, if you have any doubt don't hesitate to comment and ask further:

> https://github.com/jimmyfm/gwt-mvp-examples

Another solution may be to put an HTMLPanel in the root and then switch widgets inside the HTMLPanel by calling
[addAndReplaceElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html#addAndReplaceElement-com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IsWidget-com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element-)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have read about the MVP framework. However, even in this framework, you need a factory that initializes all your objects on onModuleLoad. My problem comes when I create the object dynamically, e.g. at click of a button

Comment: You make a good point; provided alternative possible approach :)

Comment: But, what do you do if you want to make a REST call to server, get a list of items and create item objects based on the response, during the run-time? In this case, you dont have your item objects at onModuleLoad time.

Comment: Yes/No when you work with GWT you write Java but you need to think in JavaScript.
onModuleLoad you will do an HTTP call and asynchronously when the call completes you will add the buttons/items. The http callback will be inside the onModuleLoad but it will be executed at a different time.